# Make setup of desktop application built in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, setup-deployment

I have made a desktop application, and on another PC I have not installed .NET Framework, so I want to make a setup which automatically installs the framework first and then install my desktop application and also reports of [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports).

What are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Setup and Deployment projects for this. Check this [sample tutorial for VS 2008](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/)

Comment: Its fine but i have question that if net is not available then .Net Framework wont be installed so i want to make setup that installs the Framework also.

Comment: You can deliver prerequisites as part of the install. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx. This example is for 2010, but there are guides for all versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: @user422831 yes... this project takes care of that too